# What is this C++ code using operator ^?

Tags: c++

What does this code mean?

```
int possible = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i){
   possible += (n_size[i] ^ n_size[i + 1]) < 0;
}
```

I think this is `^` XOR, but how is it working in this code? That's strange,

Because I thought when we use XOR we have just 0 or 1.
Please, help me to understand.

Comment: bitwise xor....And no...you were thinking wrong..`100^11 = 111` neither `0` nor `1`

Comment: Where did you find this? I don't get it. That expression is only going to be less than zero if only one of the operands of the exclusive OR has its negative sign bit set. What's the use of this?

Comment: @Zebrafish You literally just explained its use

Comment: @Brian Consider reading a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @Passer By So it counts the number of times any two consecutive values in an array have differing sign bits? Is there a use for this?  Where did you find this?

Comment: this n_size[] is a array with numbers between 0 and 99999. How do I know if I use this operator I you get the answer? I know 0^1 = 1, 0^0=0 ... but I don't get it yet. What book can help me?

Comment: @Zebrafish Off the top of my head, count the number of inversions? Why is this even an issue?

Comment: You *do* have 0s and 1s, just possibly 32 of them at the same time.

Comment: This is rather bad code. Understanding how `^` works here is worth investigating. Figuring out how to use this code in the real world is not; better to spend time figuring out how to do it better, i.e., **clearly**, so that readers don't have to ask what's going on.

Comment: Note that if the array `n_size` is an unsigned type or only contains positive values (or only contains negative values), the loop body won’t increment `possible`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see this line :

```
possible += (n_size[i] ^ n_size[i + 1]) < 0;
```

We don't know about `n_size` but I'll suppose it is an array of `n` `int`. So we XOR (bitwise) two consecutive terms of `n_size`, and determine the sign of the result (by comparing it to 0).

Bitwise-XOR is operating bit per bit, so (`ABCD = 1011 ^ 0101` <=> `A = 1 ^ 0` , `B = 0 ^ 1`, `C = 1 ^ 0`, `D = 1 ^ 1`).

`int` are encoded in a certain manner, which allows us to get the sign with the most-significant bit (in the number `0bX???????`, if X=1 the number is negative, else the number is positive).

So `(A ^ B) < 0` is equivalent to `(A < 0) ^ (B < 0)`.

So this line increments `possible` when two consecutive terms have not the same sign.

Finally, `possible` counts the number of consecutive terms alterning their sign.

PS : notice that `float` and `double` have their sign determined by their most-significant-bit too, so it works the same if `n_size` is an array of `float` or `double`.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, "possible" increments when two consecutive terms don't have the some sign. So, can I understand this like IF or ELSE? I'm trying to say, " if(consecutives not some sign) then increments - else (do nothing). Is it a way to see this?

Comment: @Brian yes, because true = 1 and false = 0, so "possible += boolean" means : "if (boolean) possible++;"

Answer (score 0):

As coderedoc was a little short in his comment: `^` is a bit-wise operator, just as `|` and `&`, too. Those operators are applied on every pair of corresponding bits (and for such a pair, XOR as you understood it) within two variables:

```
unsigned char c1 =                0b11001010;
unsigned char c2 =                0b10101100;
unsigned char c3 = c1 ^ c2; // == 0b01100110
unsigned char c4 = c1 & c2; // == 0b11101110
unsigned char c5 = c1 | c2; // == 0b10001000
```